# Read single row at time from mule and transform to SOAP request in mule

Tags: mule

I am facing one issue.

Requirement is I have a csv file and should transform to soap request (soap consumer component). Problem is all csv rows are transformed in one shot. In my case soap request can not handle all the rows in one request. It should be multiple call.

What I did is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:ws="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws" xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ws/current/mule-ws.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer1" wsdlLocation="CPAdministration_updated.wsdl" service="AdminService" port="AdminEndpoint" serviceAddress="http://localhost/FM/service/Hrportal?wsdlformule" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <data-mapper:config name="CSV_To_Xml_UpdateUserRequest_" transformationGraphPath="csv_to_xml_updateuserrequest__2.grf" doc:name="CSV_To_Xml_UpdateUserRequest_"/>
    <flow name="soapFlow1" doc:name="soapFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:/temp/mule" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_Xml_UpdateUserRequest_" doc:name="CSV To Xml&lt;UpdateUserRequest&gt;"  />
        <logger message="Converted xml is here #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer1" operation="UpdateUser" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use a splitter and an aggregator. Your flow might look something like this:

```
<flow name="soapFlow1" doc:name="soapFlow1">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="E:/temp/mule" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="CSV_To_Xml_UpdateUserRequest_" doc:name="CSV To Xml&lt;UpdateUserRequest&gt;"  />
    <logger message="Converted xml is here #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <splitter expression="#[xpath('//item')]" doc:name="Splitter" enableCorrelation="ALLWAYS"/>
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
    <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer1" operation="UpdateUser" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <message-chunk-aggregator failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Message Chunk Aggregator"/>
</flow>
```

The xpath expression obviously has to be changed to something that makes sense in your case.